# Python: Parameters to Run the Same Function Multiple Times

Tags: python

I am studying rotating a list, and made a function to rotate the list left and right, but how can I write a code for how many times to rotate? if that makes a sense. I want to pass it as an argument to the functions.

```py
table = [1, 10 ,20, 0, 59, 86, 32, 11, 9, 40]


def rotate_left():
    (table.append(table.pop(0)))
    return table

print(rotate_left())

def rotate_right():
    (table.insert(0,table.pop()))
    return table
    
print(rotate_right())
```

Comment: Can you elaborate with example about your issue?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense no, but if you provide step by step examples of what you want, before/after, it would make a lot more sense.

Comment: I want to run 2nd line of the function codes multiple time depending on an argument I pass. for an example, if I call a function with print(rotate_left(2)), it will rotate to left twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for loop` inside your functions and pass how many times you want to rotate as a argument.

```py
table = [1, 10 ,20, 0, 59, 86, 32, 11, 9, 40]

def rotate_left(rotate_times):
    for _ in range(rotate_times):
        table.append(table.pop(0))
    return table

>>> print(rotate_left(2))
>>> [20, 0, 59, 86, 32, 11, 9, 40, 1, 10]

def rotate_right(rotate_times):
    for _ in range(rotate_times):
        table.insert(0,table.pop())
    return table
    
>>> print(rotate_right(2))
>>> [1, 10, 20, 0, 59, 86, 32, 11, 9, 40]
```

**NOTE**

In above scenario, **be aware** of the fact that, when you pass a `list` to a method and modify it inside that method, the changes are made in `original list` unless you make a `deep copy`, because `list` is a `mutable` type.

So, when you call `rotate_left(2)`, it rotates the `original list` twice towards left. Then when you call `rotate_right(2)`, it rotates the `original list`, which is already rotated by `rotate_left(2)`, so we got the list as in initial order.

As, the functions are already modifying the `original list`, you can remove `return table` from the function (unless you want a new deep copy of list). And simply print the list after that like:

```py
def rotate_left(rotate_times):
    for _ in range(rotate_times):
        table.append(table.pop(0))
 
>>> rotate_left(2)
>>> print(table)
>>> [20, 0, 59, 86, 32, 11, 9, 40, 1, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a 'for loop' and use 'range' to decide how many times you want to rotate. In this example 'rotate_left()' is called three times:

```
table = [1, 10 ,20, 0, 59, 86, 32, 11, 9, 40]

def rotate_left():
    (table.append(table.pop(0)))
    return table


def rotate_right():
    (table.insert(0,table.pop()))
    return table
    
for i in range(3):
    print(rotate_left())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a '**loop**' and use '**range**' to decide how many times you want to loop. In this example, there is a program that asks the user in which direction and how many times to turn and calculates.

```
def rotate_left(count,table):
    
    for i in range (count):
        (table.append(table.pop(0)))
    return table

def rotate_right(count,table):
   
    for i in range (count):
        (table.insert(0,table.pop()))
    return table

def main():

    table = [1, 10 ,20, 0, 59, 86, 32, 11, 9, 40]
    isSelect = True

    while(isSelect):
        rotate = int(input("1- Rotate Left\n2- Rotate Right\n: "))
        count = int(input("\nHow many times to rotate ?\n: "))

        if((rotate == 1 or rotate == 2) and count > 0):
            isSelect = False
            if (rotate == 1):
                print(rotate_left(count,table))
                
            elif (rotate == 2):
                print(rotate_right(count,table))
        else:
            print("\nInvalid Parameter. Please choose again.\n")
    
main()
```